# How to prevent to multiple goroutines inserts document in persons collections if already exists person with same name and last name?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

How to prevent multiple goroutines to insert document in persons collections if already exists person with same name and last name ?

```
type Person struct {

    Id                      bson.ObjectId   `bson:"_id"`
    Name            string          `bson:"name"`
    LastName            string          `bson:"lastName"`

}
```

I am using Mongo with mgo driver for go language.

I try to find before insert if there is a document with same name and last name but I don't think that cover whole case when both goroutines check in same time. I tried ensure index by two fields `(name, lastName)` but it also didn't help.

Comment: it helps to start writing some code.

Comment: @SalvadorDali I try to find before insert if there is a document with same name and last name but I don't think that cover whole case when both goroutines check in same time. I tried ensure index by two fields (name, lastName) but it also didn't help

Comment: @PaolaJ. I didn't see you last comment when I posted my answer. _"I tried ensure index by two fields (name, lastName) but it also didn't help"_ Could you show _how_ you created your index and _how_ you were able to insert two documents with the same `(name, lastName)̀` ?

Answer (score 4):

> How to prevent to multiple *goroutines/process/thread/applications/...* to insert documents in persons collections if already exists person with same name and last name

**The only way** to prevent duplicate entries esp. in concurrent environment is by using an [unique index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-unique/) on `{name:1, lastname:1}`. Then in your code, you should be prepared to gracefully handle the exception raised by a potential collision.

**Never** ever *check-before-insert*, as in MongoDB you don't have transaction, so it is quite possible that a record was concurrently inserted by an other client after your *check* and before your *insert*.

---

Other peoples might certainly help you more with the correct Go syntax, but something along the lines of the following code (borrowed from [here](https://gist.github.com/border/3489566#file-mgoexample-go-L43)) will allow you to create the required index:

```
index := mgo.Index{
Key: []string{"name", "lastName"},
Unique: true,
}

err = c.EnsureIndex(index)
```

Then, every time you insert a document, you need to use the [`mgo.isDup`](http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#IsDup) function to test if an error was caused by a duplicate key. As an example from a previous [answer by @elithrar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24775437/2363712):

```
err := users.Insert(user) // where user is type *mgo.Collection
if err != nil {
    if mgo.IsDup(err) {
        // Is a duplicate key, but we don't know which one 
    }
    // Is another error
}
```

Comment: @Sylvain Leroux Should I call this only once, in main or in init function, correct ?

Comment: @PaolaJ. I've edited the answer to provide additional informations and pointers to some related documentation. But as I am *not* a Go specialist, other answers might come with more details than I can provide.